# DataStore - Schema is not initialized. DataStore will not function as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

I'm developing an application that uses AppSync with graphql from aws, but whenever I run the following line of code DataStore.start(), the following error occurs:

[ERROR] DataStore - Schema is not initialized. DataStore will not function as expected. This could happen if you have multiple versions of DataStore installed. Please see https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js/#check-for-duplicate-versions

I do not know what else to do. I even started an application from 0 and the same problem occurred. I've already deleted the node_modules folder and installed everything again, it just won't and I can't think of a way to be able to map the possible errors. Below is the code and packages.

```
import Amplify, { API, Auth, DataStore, Hub, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './src/aws-exports';
import awsapigateway from './src/aws-api-gateway';

Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
API.configure(awsapigateway);

DataStore.start()
.then(() => console.log('DataStore started'))
.catch(e => console.log('Error init datastore: ', e))
.finally(() => console.log('DataStore finally'));
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.8",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.26",
    "graphql": "16.5.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^8.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.68.2",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.1.4",
    "react-native-debugger": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-pressable-opacity": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": ">= 3.0.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-static-safe-area-insets": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.13.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.8",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "ini": "^1.3.5",
    "inquirer": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.71.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
    },
```

schema.graphql:"

```
type Subpoena @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
id: id!
status: SyncStatus!
localImageStorage: AWSJSON
}

enum SyncStatus {
PENDING
DONATE
ERROR
}
```

Comment: Have you tried one of the commands in the link in your question?

Comment: Facing the same issue, has anyone found the solution?

Comment: In my case, when I start running a query such as 'DataStore.query(Todo)', the 'schema uninitialized' error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I fought something similar for a good 24 hours, and the existing answers/documentation on the internet was useless.  It turned out I was doing something like:

```
import {MyModel} from `@src/models`;
```

If you look in that file, you'll see that it calls `initSchema()`, which is the function that needs to be called to avoid the error `DataStore - Schema is not initialized`.  Unfortunately, if you don't USE the model anywhere, the `import` gets optimized away and `initSchema()` never gets called.

Fairly egregious bug on Amazon's behalf, IMHO.  It seems reasonable that you might like to test turning on synchronization without calling `.save()` or `.query()` in your code.

Simply adding this was enough, in my case:

```
console.log(MyModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply importing the models like `import '~/src/models'` into the project root. This apparently fixes this issue for me.